# Can use this as a json object? Custom string to json parser

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm making this little parser that essentially makes json objects out of easier to input strings.  I have two input fields as you'll see and I use the first for the table name, then the next as the data page.  I'm starting extremely simple so I know this won't work for complex examples.  That'll come later.  I see i'm missing some {} but I'll add those later.  But basically my little parser spits out:

```
{pizzas:[
  size:"large";toppings:"sausage"; ]
}
```

But now I'm curious, this is technically a working json object right?  The var "object" I mean.

Here's el code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
Input like:<br/>
    table: pizzas<br/>
    data: size:"large";toppings:"sausage";<br/>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="getString(); return false;">
    table name<input type="text" name="tableJob" id="tableJob" value='example: pizzas'><br/>
    data<input type="text" name="dataJob" id="dataJob" value='example: size:"large"; toppings:"sausage";'>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="myJson"></p>
<script>
    var w, x, y, z;
    function getString(){
        x = document.getElementById("tableJob").value; //get the table from user
        y = document.getElementById("dataJob").value; //get data from user
        var object = '<p>{' + x + ':[<br/>' + '&nbsp&nbsp' + y + '&nbsp]<br/>' + '}';   
        document.getElementById("myJson").innerHTML = object;   
    }

    //now add object to our json page

</script>
</body>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
This is the correct way now:

```
<body>
Input like:<br/>
    table: "pizzas"<br/>
    data: "size":"large","toppings":"sausage",<br/>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="getString(); return false;">
    table name<input type="text" name="tableJob" id="tableJob" value='"pizzas"'><br/>
    data<input type="text" name="dataJob" id="dataJob" value='"size":"large", "toppings":"sausage,"'>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="myJson"></p>
<script>
    var w, x, y, z;
    function getString(){
        x = document.getElementById("tableJob").value; //get the table from user
        y = document.getElementById("dataJob").value; //get data from user
        var obj = '<p>{&nbsp' + x + '&nbsp:&nbsp[<br/>' + '&nbsp&nbsp{' + y + '}&nbsp]<br/>' + '}'; 
        document.getElementById("myJson").innerHTML = obj;  
        var myJsonString = 
        '{' + x + 
            ':[' + '{' + y + '} ]' +
        '}';

        alert(myJsonString);    
    }



</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You tell me! http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/object-reflection-in-javascript.html

Comment: I like this line: Sometimes, there simply is no way of knowing what you'd like to do until you get there. In such a situation

Comment: You can verify for yourself that the JSON is invalid using any of the JSON lint sites: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Ughhh JSLint. That thing is awesome and horrible.  Even when you try and choose the most lenient options that thing still is beyond strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first object you have is neither a valid JSON object nor a valid JavaScript object literal.

A proper JavaScript object literal should look like this:

```
var pizzas = {
  pizzas:[
  {size:"large",toppings:"sausage"} ], //Notice the enclosing curlys around size and toppings.
}
```

Secondly, the object you're getting back as `var object...` will look like this

```
"<p>{pizzas:[<br/>&nbsp&nbspsize:"large";toppings:"sausage"&nbsp]<br/>}"
```

which unstripped definately not an object, but stripping the HTML out:

```
"{pizzas:[size:"large";toppings:"sausage"]}"
```

still won't produce a valid JSON object and working `JSON.stringify()` won't help much either because an array can't hold key-value pairs that you're trying to insert.

Wrapping these in an object literal will fix it, see above, also remove the semi-colon that appears in your Array.

Comment: Alright I see what you're saying.  Need to strip the HTML, I talked in my initial question about the fact I was missing the braces in front of the array braces.  And yeah I just saw the semi-colon at about 3:30am last night.  So cool.  Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not valid JSON. `[...]` encloses an array, which must be a comma-separated list of elements. You have `key:value` pairs in your brackets, and they're separated by semicolons.

Is there a reason you're not using `JSON.stringify()`?